# esper grouping output multiple newEvents

Tags: grouping, esper, epl

My epl is simple:

```
select symbol, sum(price) from MarketData(symbol!='').win:time(5.5 sec) group by symbol
```

The listener:

```
update(EventBean[] newEvents, EventBean[] oldEvents) {
    System.out.println(newEvents.length); //sometimes it's greater than 1
}
```

I think it's not possible that newEvents.length > 1 for my epl.

Can someone explain this for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct that for that EPL that you posted there is always "newEvents.length=1", provided that the listener does not also receive other output and values are indeed immutable, of course.

Comment: I print the newEvents and find that when newEvents.length=n,  eventBean.get("symbol")  ouputs n different symbol.  I dont know why it will trigger different symbols at a time(an event)

Comment: Provide a simple test class